# How to get List<List<Boolean>> from Thymeleaf form in spring-boot-mvc

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Actually, my question is how to binding List<List> to Request Parameters without wrapper class

i have controller's method, that send List<List> to Thymeleaf form:

```
@PostMapping()
    public String initField(@RequestParam int sideLength, Model model) {

        List<List<Boolean>> values = gameService.initListList(sideLength);
        model.addAttribute("values", values);

        return "render";
    }
```

it goes to render page and works well.

```
<div>
    <table>
        <tr th:each="row: ${values}">
            <td th:each="cell: ${row}" th:class="${cell ? 'red' : 'green'}"></td>
    </table>
    <form action="#" method="POST" th:action="@{/step}">
        <input type="hidden" name="values" th:value="${values}">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</div>
```

But when I pass the same List<List> to the next controller's method it comes like String.

I solved this problem, but maybe there is a way to get List<List> directly in the method argument?

```
    @PostMapping("/step")
    public String nextStep(@RequestParam(name = "values") String valuesString, Model model) throws JsonProcessingException {
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        List<List<Boolean>> values = mapper.readValue(valuesString, PAYLOAD_TYPE);
        values = gameService.nextStep(values);
        model.addAttribute("values", values);
        return "render";
    }
```

Sorry for my level of english. I keep studying
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Consider sending the JSON in the request body instead, then you can use Spring's `@RequestBody` instead of `@RequestParam`.

Comment: Is a `flatMap` what you are seeking?

Comment: @Unmitigated i will try. Tnx.

Comment: @vphilipnyc i guess not. I need to pass an object List<List<Boolean>> without any modification from thymeleaf form directly to a method parameter. Tnx.

Comment: your HTML is malformed in the first example.  I don't see the closing `</tr>` tag

Comment: But I'd also rethink this design too depending on what you're trying to do

Comment: @vphilipnyc yes,  now I fixed  the tag. Thanx.  You right, i will try to do this via JSON and RequestBody as suggested by Unmitigated

Comment: Your first method should be annotated with something like `@GetMapping("something")` and not  `@PostMapping`

Comment: @vphilipnyc This is not the first method, but part of the code. Actually, my question is how to binding List<List<Boolean>> to Request Parameters without wrapper class